# Create a Required Multiselect UI Component Without the first option being selected

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform

I need to have a multi-select UI Component which is required, but does not select the first option be default? I have this set up but the first time is always selected by default. How can I do this?

```
$fieldsetSetup->addField('delivery_method', 'multiselect', 
            ['name' => 'delivery_method', 'label' => __('Delivery Method'), 'title' => __('Delivery Method'), 'required' => 'true',
            'values' => array(
                array("value" => "", "label" => "Select"),
                array("value" => "option_1", "label" => "Option 1"),
                array("value" => "option_2", "label" => "Option 2"))
            ]);
```

[image: Screenshot of the first item in the multiselect selected by default, not what I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `'value' => [],` to `addField()`, Replace your code with this

```
$fieldsetSetup->addField(
    'delivery_method', 
    'multiselect', 
    [
        'name' => 'delivery_method', 
        'label' => __('Delivery Method'), 
        'title' => __('Delivery Method'), 
        'required' => 'true',
        'value' => [],
        'values' => array(
            array("value" => "option_0", "label" => "Select"),
            array("value" => "option_1", "label" => "Option 1"),
            array("value" => "option_2", "label" => "Option 2")
        )
    ]
);
```